# Using C++ .Count() with max function from float

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a .Count with max function inside to get how many times the max value from a float type. From MSDN I didn`t understand how to make it.
Any ideeas?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking - why not give us an example?

Comment: say what? can you give an example of what you wish to do if it was possible - scenario and expected values.

Comment: Please make your question clear so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that? (Maybe not, it was hard to understand the question)

```
int count(std::vector<float> &data) {
  if ( data.empty() ) return -1;
  float maxval = data[0];
  int maxnum = 0;
  for ( std::vector<float>::iterator it = data.begin()+1; it != data.end(); ++it ) {
    if ( equal(*it, maxval) ) {
      maxnum += 1;
    } else if ( *it > maxval ) {
      maxval = *it;
      maxnum = 0;
    }
  }
  return maxnum;
}
```

equal(a, b) checks if |a - b| <= epsilon